dlopen failed: library "libhermes.so" not found react native
I’m trying to debug a React Native application on my Mac with an M1 chip in an Android environment, but I’m running into an issue. The app compiles successfully, but when it opens on an Android emulator or physical device, it crashes immediately.
Here’s the error I see in Logcat:
dlopen failed: library "libhermes.so" not found react native

I already have trying enabling hermes but this does not work and I already looking for how to solve this error at many sites but I dont found the solve

React Native Version: 0.73.0
Hermes Enabled: I already trying both ways
NDK Version: 25.2.9519653
Build Steps: I’ve already tried cleaning the project (./gradlew clean) and recompiling, but the issue persists.

If anyone has encountered this issue before or has any ideas on how to fix it, I’d greatly appreciate your guidance.
Thank you in advance for your help!

I'm not able to help you because it lacks details. But I'll share with you some tips that might help:

Check the RN architecture used to build the app in the file android/gradle.properties searches reactNativeArchitectures

Run the command ./gradlew assembleDebug

Once you've run the command, look for the android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs folder and check that all the folders it contains contain your libhermes.so. If they don't, this means that hermes is incorrectly configured

In this case, create a fresh 0.73.0 application

Check if it works well on your emulator or Android device (Activate / deactivate hermes)

If it works well, check the configuration in build.gradle and app/build.gradle

It's likely that there's a difference between your project and the new one


